# Statistics about Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP) implementation by smartphone cameras

Tags: metadata, photographs

I am writing an Android photo sharing app, and pondering whether I should implement [Extensible Metadata Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) reading from pictures taken by the smartphone/tablet/device's.

If almost no smartphone writes XMP data, then I don't need to waste my time implementing that.

So, I would welcome any data about XMP implementation in smartphones. Ideally the percentage of smartphone-taken pictures that embed XMP data, ideally per year and per country. Single numbers such as "*the XYZ phone/OS embeds XMP and had a X% market share in Indonesia in 2015*" are welcome too.

Comment: While I have no statistics to give you, I do believe that some Apple phones will embed XMP MWG region data when they identify that there is a face in the image.

Comment: @StarGeek: Thanks! That means that the data is not an empty set.